# Queremos ter a tab «unanswered» no menu de navegação?

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Muito obrigado a [@Jorge B.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7210/jorge-b) pela tradução.

---

A maioria dos sites da rede Stack Exchange têm a tab “unanswered” no menu de navegação. Por exemplo, no [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

Parece que o Stack Overflow em Português não tem esta tab. Eu falei com os meu colegas e eles disseram que não têm objeções para habilitar essa tab neste site.

Podem dizer-me, por favor, se querem o link para "perguntas por responder" no menu de navegação do Stack Overflow em Português? Têm alguma ideia porque é que nós não o habilitamos aqui?

---

Perguntas por responder são perguntas que não têm respostas aceites nem votos positivos em respostas.

Comment: Acho que seria interessante, mas já temos algo parecido http://prntscr.com/p7p98o só não é um link direto como o proposto.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente questiono-me se isso é realmente util. A maior parte das pessoas responde às perguntas do momento, ou a perguntas sobre coisas que pesquisam especificamente. Também não me lembro de ter visto essa funcionalidade a ser requisitada aqui no meta no passado.

Comment: Ao menos eu não usaria.

Comment: Então teremos? Parece que ninguém foi contra.

Answer (score 13):

Não vejo motivos para não ter a opção. Se ela existe, poderia ser habilitada.

Para quem for usar pode ser uma opção bastante útil. Para quem não usar não fará diferença uma opção a mais no menu. Se pode trazer benefícios para alguns sem implicar em malefícios aos outros, a comunidade só tem a ganhar.

> Têm alguma ideia porque é que nós não o habilitamos aqui?

Não faço ideia e provavelmente apenas a equipe da SE será capaz de responder isso, com sorte.